# Edit Windows .reg Files with sed / grep: search for a FilePath output RegPath Key Value

Tags: regex, windows, sed, grep, registry

I am currently trying to edit a full dump .reg File on Linux Mint. The Goal is to find a given path in the values an then to print out the corresponding regpath the key and the full value itself.

I know that I can achieve this using regex patterns in grep or sed unfortunately I am pretty new to the named programs.

Heres one Example: I am searching for C:\\ProgramData

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...]
"noPath0"="1.1.9103.0"
"path0Key"="C:\\ProgramData\\..."
"noPath1"="2.1.9103.0"
"path1Key"="...C:\\ProgramData\\..."

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...]
"noPath0"=dword:00000000
```

The output should be the following:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...]
"path0Key"="C:\\ProgramData\\..."
"path1Key"="...C:\\ProgramData\\..."
```

I've figured out the following two regexPattern:

```
Regpath: ^\[.[^\]]*\n
Key+Value: .*C\:\\\\ProgramData.*
```

The problem is how do I combine both patterns and use them in grep or sed or what ever is more suitable for this task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bacause of ty733420's help I was able to create a bash script that does job ... really really slowly ... but at least it works:

```
#!/bin/bash

#: <<'COMMENT'
if [ -e xx00 ]; then
    rm xx*
fi
csplit -s ./regBackup.reg.txt "/^\[/" '{*}'

for name in $(ls xx*) 
do
    #echo $name
    if grep '.*C\:\\\\Program Files.*' $name > /dev/null; then
        grep '^\[.*' $name
        grep '.*C\:\\\\Program Files.*' $name
        echo ""
    fi
done
exit 0
```

:

```
./sedS.sh > out.txt
```

Thanks for you help ty733420 :)

If someone knows how to speed this task up I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

A sed script would be a more elegant way, but for a quick-and-dirty solution, I'd write a script that runs csplit on your first regex, then grep with your second regex on each split file.  i.e.

```
if exist xx* del /q xx*
csplit myfile.reg.txt /^\[/ {*}
for %%f in (xx*) do call :search %%f

goto :EOF

:search

grep ".*C\:\\\\ProgramData.*" %1 >nul
if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" goto :EOF
grep "^\[\|.*C\:\\\\ProgramData.*" %1 
goto :EOF
```

Comment: grep '^\[.[^\[]*\|.*C\:\\\\ProgramData.*' does clutter both regex results together. Thats not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: How so?  It will display lines that contain either pattern, which is wait it seems that you're asking for.  It doesn't clutter any lines together, it just matches multiple patterns.  If this isn't what you're asking, you might want to edit to clarify what you're after.

Comment: The Problem is that I only need the Regpath if it has key's that contain the value I'm searching for. I now see that simply combining both patterns does not work. I need something like this: http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/3638/snapshot6yi.png

Comment: We're getting close to a solution. But I'm a little bit puzzled about the gotos and the labels. Just to clarify I'm editing the .reg files on Linux. The \\ before the C:\\ProgramData have not to be treated in a special way. I just wanted to show that there can be Strings before the C:\\ProgramData. I've clarified that a bit more in the main text now. I've edited the del to rm and the csplit command to csplit ./regBackup.reg.txt "/^\[/" '{*}'. The Problem I'm having currently with this is that the script throws me a : No such file or directorye. I'm not sure what he cant find.